# Half wave rectifier connected to a npn transistor - how to compute its output

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Above is the circuit i need to analyse. I already have the gain and Q-point of the first transistor, now i will have a half wave rectifier consisting of elements D1, C3 and R5.

Here's the gig, i done some simulations on LTspice and some of the results can be seen below:

[image]

Above this is the gain which i think it's pretty self explanatory.

Now the image below is the transient + stationary response when the input is 50sin(1000t), i can tell D2 glows (On) and the npn transistor is in the active region.

[image]

[image]

The Image above shows the part where i dont understand. The capacitor first charges then discharges, i can see the ripple (almost non existent), but then it just goes up and up. Why does that happen? How can i explain that on a general input? Of course if i increase the time to get rid of the transient part all i see is a DC signal which is what i want as my input voltage for Q2.

On a normal half wave rectifier with a capacitor this is what i was expecting:

[image]

Vout always stays below Vp-VDon

Answer (score 0):

So long as the voltage at Va averages less than zero current is flowing through D1

*Wait, what?*

Q1 forms a common emitter amplifier, with sensible choices of R1.R2.R3 an inverted an amplified image of the input will be present at the collector

the voltasge swings here are coupled through the capacitor to node V1
were it just R4 connected to this node the signal here would be centred on 0V 
but D1 steals capacitor current when the voltage here it is sufficiently above the charge level in C3,

as a result the signal here is centred slightly below zero and a net DC current flows up through R4 and is pushed in pulses through D1 by the action of Q1 and C2

The only escape from C3 is via R5 and then Q2 so current flows through Q2 base turinig Q2 on and lighting the LED.